# Is there a way to use HP Fortify 360 to scan a single file?

Tags: security, fortify

It takes so long to process the entire project just to see if you've fixed one problem.  Is there a way to just scan one page to make the process quicker while debugging?  Assuming there are no dependencies?  I can always run the entire project through after I've cleared some of the errors listed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the Fortify plug-in into your IDE (eclipse or Visual Studio). Open your file in that IDE and run the scan. Assuming you have a bug tracker (bugzilla or Jira) associated with your IDE, you can post the bug for later action.

I advise against uploaded the resulting FPR file into the Software Security Center as it will not be comparable to your existing project FPR files.

Comment: Also expect numerous false positives from missing code and other dependencies.